# DBT docs generate - How to give the specific branding to the documentation website

Tags: etl, modeling, dbt, branding, fishtown-analytics

How to replace the DBT logo with some other image in the website header, generated by dbt docs generate command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation consists of an `index.html` file, which loads data from the artifact files ([source](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/cmd-docs)).

If you edit the `index.html` file you will be able to customise it as you wish. Note that each time you run `dbt docs generate` the file will be re-copied into your target folder, so you’ll need some mechanism for either copying the artifacts to wherever your new index.html` is located or overwriting the file with your customised version.

Comment: How can I overwrite only some parts of index.html while retaining the other parts as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the file in the source folder, I believe the `index.html` file is copied from the `dbt installation folder` to the `target` folder everytime you run `dbt docs generate`. You can customize the `index.html` file from that directory and then you don't have to worry about making any changes when you run `dbt docs generate`.

This is what I'd do:

- Find `index.html` file in the `dbt installation directory` add the line

  ```
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='/styles.css' />
  ```

  in the `<head>` tag. This way, you only have to make this change again when you update `dbt`
- Add a `styles.css` file in your `target` folder and then target the class of the dbt logo. If you change the background color of the logo, you should be fine and you will not have to re-copy every time you run `dbt docs generate`.

  ```
   .logo {
       background-image: url(<<path or url to your image>>);
       background-color: transparent;
  }
  ```

You can adjust other properties like `background-repeat, background-position, background-size, background-color` according to your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to expand on @Kay answer a bit as it helped me tremendously.

To find the dbt installation folder on Windows, you need to go into your `venv` folder within your project and navigate down to the `dbt/include` folder.  This may be different for different projects/OS, so here is my path to help shed light on where this may be:

`venv` --> `Lib` --> `site_packages` --> `dbt` --> `include` --> `index.html`

Once you have located the file, follow the steps in [@Kay answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318855/6820436).  The only modification that I made is to add in a corresponding file path in the HTML added to the `index.html` file

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='**..dbt_project_path**/styles.css' />`

Next, in your dbt project, go and add that specific folder to your root dbt project directory.  From there, add in your `.css` file.  By aligning the `index.html` file path to the file path created in your dbt project, you will always reference the .css (or any other modifications you have) when running the `dbt docs generate` command.